# How to display a pop up notification laravel using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How to display a pop-up notification in admin side when a customer click an order?. Now its not getting the pop-up notification?.when inspect the values getting.

var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

```
function playAudio() {
    audio.play();
}

function pauseAudio() {
    audio.pause();
}
```

```
Ajax

   <script>
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('get-order-data')}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            let data = response.data;
        
            if (data.new_order > 0) {
                playAudio();
                $('#popup-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
            }
    
            
        },
    });
}, 1000);
```

Controller

```
public function order_data()
{
    $new_order = DB::table('orders')->where(['checked' => 0])->count();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 1,
        'data' => ['new_order' => $new_order]
    ]);
}
```

### pop up code

```
<div class="modal" id="popup-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <center>
                        <h2 style="color: rgba(96,96,96,0.68)">
                            <i class="tio-shopping-cart-outlined"></i> You have new order, Check Please.
                        </h2>
                        <hr>
                        
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of just duplicating text you should have posted what works, what doesn't or any errors you get

Comment: pop up is not displaying @brombeer

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the popup through modal window. You can trigger the modal window through javascript. I hope the below code will be useful for you. Try this code in jsFiddle with jQuery enabled. Append the javascript code inside the ajax code where you need to display the notification.

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
     $("#myModal").modal('show');
    })
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn">
    Submit
    </button>
```

Comment: @ sujith Sandeep can you tell how to use in this code

Comment: setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('get-order-data')}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            let data = response.data;
        
            if (data.new_order > 0) {
                playAudio();
                $("#popup-modal").modal('show');
            }
    
            
        },
    });
}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

### Ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('get-order-data')}}',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {                       
                    $.each(response.new_order, function (key, value) { 
                        if (value.new_order > 0) {
            playAudio();
            $('#popup-modal').modal('show');
        }                        
                    });
                    }
    });
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

### **Controller**

```
public function order_data()
{
    $data = DB::table('orders')->where('checked', 0)->get();
    $count = $data->count();
    $res['new_order'] = array([
    'success' => 1,
    'new_order' => $count
    ]);
    return response()->json($res);
}
```

Comment: not showing the popup @martin Amu

Comment: @Deepu If you want to see it on page load then use: $(window).on('load', function()

Comment: Martin Amu can you add that function on my code

Comment: @Deepu code edited.

Comment: Martin Amu  not showing

Comment: @Deepu This time should work

Comment: Martin Amu  No bro not wrking.if you give your mail id i can share the code

Comment: @Deepu check your route too. martin.amu.riki@gmail.com

Comment: @ 
Martin Amu plz check